# Why do structs with an anonymous struct field not satisfy methods defined on an alias of that type?

Tags: go

I have a struct defined outside my package that I would like to attach a method to.  Due to the fact that the package is reflecting on the original type, I cannot use the alias within my struct, I have to use the original type.  Below is essentially what I'm trying to do:

```
package main

import "fmt"

type Entity struct {
    loc_x int
    loc_y int
}

type Player struct {
    Entity
    name string
}

type Alias Entity

func (e Alias) PrintLocation() {
    fmt.Printf("(%v, %v)", e.loc_x, e.loc_y)
}

func main() {
    player := new(Player)
    player.PrintLocation()
}
```

Attempting to compile this results in `type *Player has no field or method PrintLocation`.  If I define the `PrintLocation()` method on `Entity`, it works.  If `Alias` and `Entity` are the same exact thing, why is the compiler complaining?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That is not an alias. `byte` and `uint8` are aliases, but what you have created is a new type ,`Alias`, with the underlying type of `Entity`.

Different types have their own set of methods and doesn't inherit them from the underlying type.

So `Entity` has no methods at all, and `Alias` has the method of `PrintLocation()`.

Comment: I appreciate the answer!  It seems counter intuitive that `Alias` wouldn't have an "is-a" relationship to `Entity`.  What is the practical purpose of being able to define a type in that fashion, then?

Comment: @w.brian Making new types like that is useful when you want to add methods (to implement interfaces) to a type that you don't control. In some cases you might even want, in a single package, have it. Let's say you have a struct that you encode using `json.Marshal`, but you also need to have a "light" version of that encoding where several fields are not included; then you can create a new type, add a MarshalJSON() function to the new type and just convert to the new type before calling `json.Marshal`.

Comment: @w.brian Oh, by the way. If you want to "inherit" methods, the way to do that is called "embedding" (See [Effective Go](http://golang.org/doc/effective_go.html#embedding)). It does work a bit different than what you try to achieve, but you might be able to use it with some refactoring.

Answer (score 1):

There're a few things that are wrong here:

1 - `new(Player)` returns a pointer to a newly allocated zero value of type `Player`
http://golang.org/doc/effective_go.html#allocation_new

You should use `Player{}` instead.

2 - The receiver of your `PrintLocation` method is `Alias`, which has nothing to do with `Entity` or `Player`.

Comment: Why would he need a value of type `Player` instead of a `*Player`?